# Unable to remove the randomly added UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I added a custom uiview randomly and tried to remove the uiview when i click on the particular location(top right of the UIVIew) of that uiview,but I am able to remove the last generated uiview but not the all uiviews that are randomly added.

Here is what I done :

```
- (IBAction)addView:(id)sender {

    NSString *min = @"60"; //Get the current text from your minimum and maximum textfields.
    NSString *max = @"110";

    int randNum = rand() % ([max intValue] - [min intValue]) + [min intValue];
    butLab = [[buttonLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(randNum, randNum, 82, 36)];

    [self.view addSubview:butLab];


}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:butLab];
    NSLog(@"%f %f",locationPoint.x,locationPoint.y);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(butLab.bounds, [touches.anyObject  locationInView:butLab])==YES){
        if ( (locationPoint.x>=64 && locationPoint.x<=80)
         &&  (locationPoint.y>=3  && locationPoint.y<=12) ) {

            NSLog(@"pressed close button");
           [butLab removeFromSuperview]; //here when i clicked on top right,only the last view that is added is getting removed
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me the best way to remove the  UIViews  one by one?

Comment: @kylecman, your suggestion won't work. First of all, setting the pointer to nil doesn't remove the object form the superview. Secondly, butLab only points to the last object he created which is why he's having this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the method, addView:, is called, you redefine butLab to be a new buttonLabel, so that's why only the last one is removed. When you create a buttonLabel, you should add it to an array, and have all the members of the array call removeFromSuperview on themselves,

```
[buttonLabelsArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Another way to do it without an array, would be to loop through self.view's subviews, and call removeFromSuperview on any object that is of the class buttonLabel.

**After Edit:**

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

```
for (buttonLabel *but in buttonLabelArray) {
     CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:but];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(but.bounds, [touches.anyObject  locationInView:but])==YES){
        if ( (locationPoint.x>=64 && locationPoint.x<=80)
            &&  (locationPoint.y>=3  && locationPoint.y<=12) ) {

            NSLog(@"pressed close button");
            [but removeFromSuperview]; //here when i clicked on top right,only the last view that is added is getting removed
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how should I add the subview to an array?

Comment: @tnan, create an NSMutableArray and use addObject, [myMutableArray addObject:butLab]; Do this right after the line where you alloc init butLab. Or, do it the other way I suggested without an array.

Comment: i tried with the array,but it is removing all the subviews. I do not want like that. I need to remove the subview one by one and that too when i touch at the top right of that uiview.

Comment: consider like this, i am adding the uiview with the red mark on top right of that view,so when i click on that red mark that view should be removed.

Comment: @tnan, You need to change you touchesBegan method then. You need to put your if statement inside a loop that loops through all the buttonLabel objects in your array. See my edit.

Comment: still the same @rdelmar

Comment: @tnan, What is still the same?

Comment: @tnan, I made one change in the touchesBegan method and have updated my code to show that. The locationPoint line needs to be inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom `UIView`that has an `UIButton` at its top right corner and remove them all when this button is touched up inside

Comment: I am trying to do without a button. I will go with this if nothing work out for me.